# Editable Tables with KnockoutJS with Footable

Tags: html, knockout.js

A decision has been made with the department I work out to use [Footable](http://fooplugins.com/plugins/footable-jquery/) to provide Responsive grid layouts within an existing web framework.  One added idea was to make the grids editable and I've managed to get this going using KnockoutJS.  I'm finding an interesting affect though when trying to bind input fields in the hidden row of fields.

If I show a readonly view of my rowdata using  elements then the knockout binding works fine and all rows show the data when I press the + symbol expanding the row, although if I replace the label with an  then the text boxes are empty.  Also the dirty flag doesn't respond to changes.

Any of the fields which are set to display in the main row show the value fine and triggers the dirty flag on edit although if I narrow the browser window they go blank.

Given plain label elements bind without an issue in this second row of the footable can anyone suggest why the binding fails when it's an input?  I can't work out if it's a Knockout or Footable thing.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Footable now supports it starting from 2.0.3]**

Footable as such does not support form input elements properly. In our project we had multiple pages which required editing and I have made changes to the footable code to enable editing. You can try with the following it also includes the documentation:

https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/pull/285

The idea is to create a data variable for every td with unique id and bind it to the row and its details and detach the contents from row to detail and vice versa based on the visibility.

**Row**

```
<tr class="footable-detail-show" style="display: table-row;">
    ....
    <td style="display: none;" data-bind-name="bind-1413864326707-4"></td>
    ....
</tr>
```

**Details**

```
<tr class="footable-row-detail">
    ....
        <div class="footable-row-detail-value" data-bind-value="bind-1413864326707-4">
            <input id="abc" type="text" value="200">
        </div>
    .....
</tr>
```

For it to work it expects footable is initialized after the table contains all the data (Not required when data-editable="true") and any changes made are strictly on the input elements based on say id or the elements selector and not based on the td selector. Say for example changes to #abc are preserved but if you make changes to `<td style="display: none;" data-bind-name="bind-1413864326707-4">` they are lost.

Check the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/habeebhassan/f8L8jt6p/

Comment: Mm, thanks for that.  In the end I went with a modal popup window to allow editing of the rows.  Got a little messy as I was using KnockoutJS and watned to copy the underlying rowdata to allow a cancel button with easy ditching of changes on the popup.  Ultimately though, our business group really want an editable grid.  I'll have a look at this latest version.

Thanks again

Comment: Hi, I just gave that version a go, but noticed some odd behaviour.  I have an editable field marked <th data-hide="phone"...  which has a text input with a number in it.  There is also a hidden read only label.  The phone one appears file and if I reduce the width as narrow as possible, the editable field disappears.  Then when I expand it shows up again correctly.  BUT, if I expand the hidden area by clicking the + on the left, then reduce, the text input shows in the list, but then expanding again, the input disappears complete.  This is with or without data-editable.

Comment: Check this demo on http://jsfiddle.net/habeebhassan/f8L8jt6p/ .It could be that you are initializing footable before you are binding your viewmodel to your table. You also need to fire the footable redraw event if you are dynamically attaching any new code.

Comment: Hey, there was a bug please check with the new code

Comment: One interesting visual issue I just found is if you set a <label..> other elements with class="form-control" (bootstrap class) then the input appears beneath the + footable-toggle button, not beside it.
I can have a look at it sometime, but thought I'd mention it if you know of the top of your head (having been through the code before).

Comment: Also, title="..." attributes set for table column headers end up heaving the attr value rendered next to the header name in the hidden row.

I've also has a scenario where the expanded rows become separated from the parent visible row if we sort by our columns, but I think that's more our old table sort doing it.  I recall seeing something in Footable about sorting, so I'll try that out first.

Comment: if you check the css for form-control it is defined as block level and width as 100%. You will need to do a bit of tweaking with the css for your specific case to achieve this. If your first column has input elements and the second column as text, probably you may want to move the expand to the second column (you can achieve this by setting the right data-attribute - check footable). Your second comment -- I was not able to reproduce. If you can give a link to js fiddle code. I can give you the css which can work for you.